# bash: /generic_send_tcp: No such file or directory in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, generics, tcp, send

[image]

I try to use Spike, and when I execute `./generic_send_tdp`, it shows

> "bash: /generic_send_tcp: No such file or directory"

Comment: Do you execute `./generic_send_tdp`, `./generic_send_tcp`, or `/generic_send_tcp`? You have three different things in your question!

Comment: I execute ./generic_send_tcp and it shows the same thing. Sorry for typo

Comment: Do you have an executable called `generic_send_tcp` in the current working directory?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Then why would you expect that command to work? That command says to execute an executable file called `generic_send_tcp` in the current working directory.

Comment: I have a file generic_send_tcp.c in my working directory. can you please help me to make work?  does it take effect?